# How to display chosen poll option alongside overall results in Django

Tags: python, django, routes

I'm new to Python & Django and I have been following the App tutorial that the Django Documentation has.

I have made the routes and everything is working, the issue I am having is that I want to be able to show what poll option the user chose on the result page. (The result page currently only shows the overall result of the poll, which I do want to keep but I also want to display the selected choice in addition to that.) The user does not have to be logged in so I haven't created a foreign key to tie a user to their vote.

I figured out a way to add the selected choice primary key to the URL but as i'm using class based views i'm not sure how to get that value in the result view.

```
urls.py

...
app_name = "polls"
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
        path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
        path('<int:pk>/results/<int:choice_id>', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
        path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    ]
```

...

```
views.py

def vote(request, question_id):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        try:
            selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
        ... #removed the test part
        else:
            selected_choice.votes += 1
            selected_choice.save()                
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id, selected_choice.id)))


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'
```

Comment: You can override [`get_context_data()`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/#get_context_data) in your `DetailView` in order to add more variables to the context. `self.kwargs` will contain the values from the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite `get_contect_data` as in example in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering):

```
class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['choice'] = kwargs['choice_id']
        return context
```

Then you can use `{{choice}}` tag in your template

However, I think it is better to store that kind of variables in user [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/) (anonymous).

Save value in session:

```
def vote(request, question_id):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        try:
            selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
        ... #removed the test part
        else:
            selected_choice.votes += 1
            selected_choice.save()
            request.session['choice'] = selected_choice.id # here we are saving value to session   
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id)))

class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'
```

Now you can access `request.session.choice` anywhere:

For example, in template use tag `{{request.session.choice}}`.